# csharp comparing a user entered expiration date to todays date to check for validity

Tags: c#, date

c sharp

I am trying to check a users input to an expiration date field and verify that the date is after todays date.

The input is in the format yyyy-MM-DD

I am having a problem getting the string in to a valid DateTime Format

The example i found used

System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeStyles.None
which will not compile

Here is my code

```
    // initate with button

     private void ChkDateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                stInputDate = DateTxtBx.Text;  // input from text box
                // bExpDateLater already defined as bool
                bExpDateLater = ValidateExpDate(stInputDate);

                if (bExpDateLater == true)
                {
                    OutputTxtBox.Text = "This is a valid Date";
                }
                else
                {
                    OutputTxtBox.Text = "This is not a valid Date";
                }

            }

    // validate date as later than today

    private bool ValidateExpDate(string expdate)
            {
                // expdate string format yyyy-MM-dd
                DateTime sDateNow = DateTime.Now;

                // remove hyphen from date
                expdate = expdate.Replace("-", "");
                string format = "yyyyMMdd";
                DateTime sCompareDate;
                DateTime.TryParseExact(expdate, format,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeStyles.None, out sCompareDate);

                if (sDateNow < sCompareDate)
                {
                    return true;

                }
                else
               {

                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The input is in the format yyyy-MM-DD not  yyy-MM-DD

Comment: You're missing a comma - it should be `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None`

Comment: The format you are using in the code is `yyyyMMdd`, not `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: TryParseExact() returns a boolean as to whether it was successful. You should probably use that to be sure you don't throw on the following lines.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with how I was trying to parse the date

This was the solution

```
    private bool ValidateExpDate(string expdate)
    {
        // expdate string format yyyy-MM-dd
        DateTime dtDateNow = DateTime.Now;
        // DateTime shortDateNow = dtDateNow.ToShortTimeString;

        // remove hyphen from date
        expdate = expdate.Replace("-", "");
        string format = "yyyyMMdd";

        DateTime dtCompareDate = DateTime.ParseExact(expdate, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        if (dtDateNow < dtCompareDate)
        {
            return true;

        }
        else
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```